# What service should I use if I want to share a volume across multiple Windows EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage

I've looked at EFS and EBS Multi-Attach, but neither support Windows. I've looked at S3, but it's blob storage (I guess?), not a proper volume.

I just want a simple volume that I can mount from multiple instances. I realize I could just set up a share on one of the instances, but I'd prefer it not be instance-dependent (IE if I do scaling, etc).

Ideally I'd be able to access it as a mounted disk, but I'd also be fine with a mapped network drive.

Is there an AWS service that will do this?

Comment: FSX for windows

Comment: Interesting. The "3rd party" thing is a turn off, but I guess I'll give it a go with OpenZFS...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mount an S3 bucket on ec2 instances.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/mounting-amazon-s3-to-an-amazon-ec2-instance-using-a-private-connection-to-s3-file-gateway/